# Generate a random string excluding certain special characters in python

Tags: python, string, random

I just started learning coding. I was trying to create a password generator in python. After researching this website, I found that I can use,

```
random.SystemRandom().choice(string.punctuation)
```

My question is, How can I generate random characters from the set of punctuation excluding the special characters `'#$~'` etc?

```
s=random.SystemRandom().choice(string.punctuation)
```

I would like my variable s to have random special characters excluding a few of my choice.

Comment: You create a string with all the characters from the desired alphabet and run `random.choice()` on it.

Comment: Agree with @KlausD., it's the easiest solution you can come up.

Answer (score 1):

For a password that does not use special characters, I like to combine `os.urandom` with `base64.b64encode`:

```
In [1]: import os                                                                                        

In [2]: import base64                                                                                    

In [3]: base64.b64encode(os.urandom(12), b'__').decode()                                                 
Out[3]: 'Rb1fOnnzO2H4cCYy'

In [4]: base64.b64encode(os.urandom(12), b'__').decode()                                                 
Out[4]: 'sDX8bVqAB7iyf9S1'
```

The only downside is that it can leave '=' characters at the end of the password depending on the length of the input data.

I use the following code to get around that:

```
In [1]: import base64 
   ...: import os                                                                                        

In [2]: def genpw(length): 
   ...:     """ 
   ...:     Generate a random password. 
   ...:  
   ...:     Arguments: 
   ...:         length: Length of the requested password. 
   ...:  
   ...:     Returns: 
   ...:         A password string. 
   ...:     """ 
   ...:     n = roundup(length) 
   ...:     d = os.urandom(n) 
   ...:     return base64.b64encode(d, b'__').decode()[:length] 
   ...:  
   ...:  
   ...: def roundup(characters): 
   ...:     """ 
   ...:     Prevent '=' at the end of base64 encoded strings. 
   ...:  
   ...:     This is done by rounding up the number of characters. 
   ...:  
   ...:     Arguments: 
   ...:         characters: The number of requested (8-bit) characters. 
   ...:  
   ...:     Returns: 
   ...:         The revised number. 
   ...:     """ 
   ...:     bits = characters * 6 
   ...:     upto = 24 
   ...:     rem = bits % upto 
   ...:     if rem: 
   ...:         bits += (upto - rem) 
   ...:     return int(bits / 8) 
   ...:                                                                                                  

In [3]: genpw(7)                                                                                         
Out[3]: 'ctnJF_a'

In [4]: genpw(24)                                                                                        
Out[4]: 'if7EOy8ZR_O7EAXGSwXouCiU'

In [5]: genpw(24)                                                                                        
Out[5]: 'K_6XvVg_zCMRECLayy3oHejg'

In [6]: genpw(24)                                                                                        
Out[6]: 'xEyovBztluUM8XHIoNRRacp1'
```

You can find the complete command-line script in one of my [github repos](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts) under the name `genpw.py`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just a question, is possible to filter what characters can be generated?

Comment: @crissal There are several ways. You cound change the second argument to `b64encode`, which determines how \ and + are encoded.  Second, you could use e.g. `str.translate`. Third, you could use another encoding like `base64.a85encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a string like this:

`characters = "[all the characters you want]"`

and just pick a random character with `characters[random.randint(0, len(characters))]`

Comment: That's not Python.

Comment: Yup, you don't have to declare variable, my mistake

Comment: And what you did there can be done with simply `random.choice(characters)`.